# Prolog Sorting a List of Structure, arithmetic error

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd

I've been trying to sort a list of structure.

The structure is like this

```
% person(Name, Weight).
person(tom, 65).
person(dan, 70).
person(mike, 80).
```

And the list would be like this

```
List = [person(tom, 65), person(dan, 70), person(mike, 80)].
```

I want to sort the list from greatest weight to least. Like this:

```
SortList = [person(mike, 80), person(dan, 70), person(tom, 65)].
```

So far I have this:

```
sortListPerson([], []).
sortListPerson([person(NameP, WP)|Rest], Result):-
     sortListPerson(Rest, List),
     insertPerson(person(NameP, WP), List, Result).

insertPerson(person(NameP, WP), [], [person(NameP, WP)]).
insertPerson(person(NameP1, WP1), [person(NameP2, WP2)|Rest],   [person(NameP1, WP1)|List]):-
    integer(WP1),
    integer(WP2),
    WP1 @>= WP2,
    insertPerson(person(NameP2, WP2), Rest, List).
insertPerson(person(NameP1, WP1), [person(NameP2, WP2)|Rest], [person(NameP2, WP2)|List]):-
    integer(WP1),
    integer(WP2),
    WP1 @< WP2,
    insertInPlace(person(NameP1, WP1), Rest, List).
```

I've tried with a list of two persons and it works:

```
?- sortListPerson([person(a, 10), person(b, 30)], SortList).

SortList = [person(b,30),person(a,10)] ? ;
```

But when I try with a list of 3 or more person appears an error:

```
?- sortListPerson([person(a, 10), person(b, 30), person(c, 40)], SortList).
{ERROR: arithmetic:>=/2 - expected an arithmetically evaluable expression, found person(a,10)}

no
?-
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You don't actually have `person(Name, Weight).` written as a fact, do you?

Comment: I don't see `>=/2` being used anywhere in the code you show, but the error is clearly regarding this operator. Perhaps there's an issue in your `insertInPlace/3` predicate, which isn't shown.

Comment: @Danick: Is there a reason why you have edited out the [tag:clpfd] tag? It seems relevant for your question; http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clpfd/info.

Comment: @Matt Because I'm not suppose to use clpfd

Comment: @Danick: The tag is not meant to indicate what you are allowed to use; it is meant to help later readers who are looking for this topic find pertaining questions! Please restore the [tag:clpfd] tag for this question, since CLP(FD) constraints are the solution for such problems. This is also clearly reflected in *both* answers.

Comment: @Matt: So why this now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I see it your insertion-sort is okay, except for the second clause of `insertPerson/3`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

insertPerson(person(N,W), [], [person(N,W)]).
insertPerson(person(N1,W1), [person(N2,W2)|Ps], [person(N1,W1),person(N2,W2)|Ps]) :-
   W1 #>= W2.                                   % If Ps is in order, we're done!
insertPerson(person(N1,W1), [person(N2,W2)|Ps], [person(N2,W2)|Qs]) :-
   W1 #< W2,
   insertPerson(person(N1,W1), Ps, Qs).
```

Sample query:

```
?- sortListPerson([person(tom,65),person(dan,70),person(mike,80)], Xs).
Xs = [person(mike,80),person(dan,70),person(tom,65)] ;
false.
```

Comment: I have tried your optimization but the error still there. I'm not allowed to use clp.

Comment: @Danick. That's bad. Using `>=` instead of `#>=` and `<` instead of `#<` in above code works just as well. What answers do *you* get for above query `?- sortListPerson([person(tom,65),person(dan,70),person(mike,80)], Xs).` -- or do you get error(s) and if so which ones?

Comment: @Danick. Do you have to write your own sort? If not, why not use the built-in predicate `keysort/2`? It would fit nicely!

Comment: I get error:
`ERROR: arithmetic:>=/2 - expected an arithmetically evaluable expression, found person(tom,65)`

Comment: Unfortunately I have to write my own sort. Yes `keysort/2` would be perfect.

Comment: I feel really stupid, in the same file I got another sort list function and I mixed without knowing it. My bad, the code actually works.
Thanks for the help anyway. I should really check my eyes u_u

Comment: @Danick. Take it easy! Take comfort in the knowledge that (with computers) *no* game is a home game.

Answer (score 5):

The error comes from the fact that the built-in arithmetic operators like `<` and `=<` only work on instantiated terms (i.e. `1 < 2` is true but `1 < X` throws the exception you mentioned). If you use constraints, the code becomes something like:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

smallest_in_rest_vars(person(N,A), [person(N,A)], [], [A]).
smallest_in_rest_vars(person(N,A), [person(N1,A1) | Ps],    % <-- this one fails without clpfd
                      [person(N1,A1) | Rs], [A1|Vs] ) :-
    A #=< A1,
    smallest_in_rest_vars(person(N,A), Ps, Rs, Vs).
smallest_in_rest_vars(person(N1,A1), [person(N1,A1) | Ps],
                      [person(N,A) | Rs], [A1|Vs] ) :-
    A #> A1,
    smallest_in_rest_vars(person(N,A), Ps, Rs, Vs).

list_sorted([],[], []).
list_sorted(L, [Smallest|SortedRest], Vars) :-
    smallest_in_rest_vars(Smallest, L, Rest, Vars0),
    list_sorted(Rest, SortedRest, Vars1),
    append(Vars0, Vars1, Vars).
```

I assume your `insertInPlace` predicate is similar to `smallest_in_rest_vars`, only without the explicit list of variables `Vs` which is useful for labeling (which we don't need in this case). If I would not use constraints, I'd get the following error when I query with your list:

```
ERROR: =</2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (9) smallest_in_rest_vars(_G400, [person(tom, 65), person(dan, 70), person(mike, 80)], [person(_G406, _G407)], _G462) ?
```

The reason is that the clause which is marked in the example, we don't know anything about the new person `N1` yet, which leads to a comparison `80 < A1`. I found using clpfd much easier to think about, but when you give us your `insertInPlace`, we might find a non-clp solution too.

Comment: Yes, but if **X** and **Y** are instantiated term that are numbers, I don't understand the error. What is looks weird to me is that prolog found person(a, 20) the entire structure.
I'm not allow to use CLP, thanks anyway.

Comment: Is it possible that your insertInPlace does not unify with person(N,Y) in the head of one clause, but in the others it does?

Comment: I have printed the two values before comparing it and it shows me that they are numbers. I have use `write(Weight)`

Comment: I can't see the variable ```Weight``` in your implementation - can you add the part containing it (I assume insertPerson) )to the Question?